# Error with screen brightness on Samsung Galaxy J7 prime

Tags: screen, screen-brightness, samsung-galaxy-j7

I have a Samsung galaxy J7 prime SM-G610M Duos with Android 7.0 operating system. I have noticed something curious with the phone, is that sometimes the full screen of the phone does a slight flicker.

It happens a few times when I close an application, when one calls the other (for example share a MEGA file in whatsapp).

Another fact, and this one always happens, is with youtube, when you open it, the brightness decreases, and when I write in the search bar and I already have some text I write when I press the spacebar, it blinks.

Once, also the brightness gauge was hung, and the brightness of the screen was set to maximum, no matter if it decreased it, it remained at maximum. Although then it settled with just lock the screen and turn on again.

Does anyone know why this happens?
Is it a software problem?

I read some articles online and they say that the screen should be changed.

I have little time with the phone, and it is in perfect condition, without any accidents. So I am inclined to make it a software bug, and that is how I would solve it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try factory reset your phone 
If it didn't work flash you're phone to another android version

Comment: We don't generally recommend the "nuclear option" first, without exploring the more accessible remediation.